# Combining two SQL queries with different row size

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following queries:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    EnrolledDate,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EnrolledTimeUtc, EnrollmentCompleteTimeUtc) as Enroll
FROM StudentEnrollment
WHERE EnrolledTimeUtc IS NOT NULL


SELECT
    AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EnrolledTimeUtc, EnrollmentCompleteTimeUtc)) as AvgEnrollmentTime,
    STDEV(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EnrolledTimeUtc, EnrollmentCompleteTimeUtc)) as  EnrollmentStDev 
FROM StudentEnrollment
WHERE EnrolledTimeUtc IS NOT NULL
```

I am trying to combine these queries so that i can see the data in one table. Is it possible to do it?

I tried combining them using

```
SELECT (SELECT... ), (SELECT...)
```

But as the number of rows don't match the above script does not work.

The first query returns something like this:

```
EnrolledDate                Enroll
2013-04-24 23:17:59.613     1
2013-04-24 23:18:01.753     5
2013-04-24 23:18:03.517     10
2013-04-24 23:18:05.703     8
```

Second query returns:

```
AvgEnrollmentTime EnrollmentStDev
19                22.1125
```

I want these two tables combined so it should show like:

```
EnrolledDate                Enroll       AvgEnrollmentTime EnrollmentStDev
2013-04-24 23:17:59.613     1            19                22.1125
2013-04-24 23:18:01.753     5
2013-04-24 23:18:03.517     10
2013-04-24 23:18:05.703     8
```

After using Hiren's script I get it to work like this:

```
EnrolledDate                Enroll       AvgEnrollmentTime EnrollmentStDev
2013-04-24 23:17:59.613     1            19                22.1125
2013-04-24 23:18:01.753     5            Null              Null
2013-04-24 23:18:03.517     10           Null              Null
2013-04-24 23:18:05.703     8            Null              Null
```

But is it possible to make it look like this rather?

```
EnrolledDate                Enroll       AvgEnrollmentTime EnrollmentStDev
2013-04-24 23:17:59.613     1            19                22.1125
2013-04-24 23:18:01.753     5            19                22.1125
2013-04-24 23:18:03.517     10           19                22.1125
2013-04-24 23:18:05.703     8            19                22.1125
```

Comment: What does "combine these queries" mean? Does that mean you want one row with all of the values, or does that mean you want multiple rows? You need to [edit] your question to provide a sample your data, the output you're getting now for each query, and what you'd like your combined output to look like based on that sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just roll all the select statements into one query?

Comment: @KenWhite - Sorry, I updated my question to show what i am exactly looking for.

Comment: @ChristopherBales - I tried but as number of rows are different it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to do it. you have to use full outer join for it and join two tables using row numbers . 
you can do something like following query :

```
SELECT A.EnrolledDate , A.Enroll ,B.AvgEnrollmentTime , B.EnrollmentStDev
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 10
    EnrolledDate,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EnrolledTimeUtc, EnrollmentCompleteTimeUtc) as Enroll
    FROM StudentEnrollment
    WHERE EnrolledTimeUtc IS NOT NULL
) AS A
,
(
    SELECT
    AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EnrolledTimeUtc, EnrollmentCompleteTimeUtc)) as AvgEnrollmentTime,
    STDEV(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EnrolledTimeUtc, EnrollmentCompleteTimeUtc)) as  EnrollmentStDev 
    FROM StudentEnrollment
    WHERE EnrolledTimeUtc IS NOT NULL
) AS B
```

Comment: I tried it but getting following error: EnrolledTimeUtc is invalid in the select list becasue it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: It works now but few things: I get null values now is there a way to remove that? Also is there a way not to show CNT?

Comment: modified the query for not to show CNT . but What is the problem for NULL values ? can you provide me a screen shot of it so that i can get better idea .

Comment: Or instead of null is there a way to copy 1st row values in all other null values??

Comment: I updated my question to show you what i mean by NULL values?

Comment: in that case you don't need to use join . i modified the query check it .

Comment: Also i dont think you need CNT now. If you modify that i will mark this as correct answer.